# How to iterate through json_encode array?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I have an input multiple file where I upload images in "edit.php". When the form is submitted, it goes to "admin.php". So I created a "photo_path" array and pushed each image files into the "photo_path" array then store it in "images" column in SQL. but the thing is array is not allowed to be stored in SQL so I json_encoded my array so that I can store the whole array inside "images" column in SQL. My question is, how do I iterate json_encoded array (which is "images" column in SQL) in javascript?

here is my code:

edit.php

```
 <input type='file' id="hmo_image" onchange="loadHmoImage(event)" name="hmo_image[]" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" multiple />
```

admin.php

```
    if(isset($_FILES['hmo_image']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['hmo_image']['name'])){
        
            foreach($_FILES['hmo_image']['name'] as $key => $value){
                
                $file_name = $this->_generateRandomString();
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/hmo_card';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg/jpeg/png';
                $config['max_size'] = '999999';
                $config['file_name'] = $file_name;
                $file_name = $_FILES['hmo_image']['name'][$key];
                //Load Upload Library
            
                array_push($photo_path_hmo, 'uploads/hmo_card/'.$file_name);
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->do_upload('hmo_image');
            }

            var_dump($photo_path_hmo);
        }

$arr = array(
'hmo_image' => json_encode($photo_path_hmo))
```

Comment: Just `json_decode ()` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should json_decode it. Json encode turns data into a string, so you must turn it back into array with json_decode.

Comment: but it says json_decode is not a function in jquery where I call data.images

Comment: @Mengzz in JS you should use JSON.parse(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse